# Disable Scrolling on Body

Tags: html, css, scroll

I would like to disable scrolling on the HTML `body` completely. I have tried the following options:

- `overflow: hidden;` (not working, did not disable scrolling, it just hid the scrollbar)
- `position: fixed;` (this worked, but it scrolled completely to the top, which is unacceptable for this specific application)

I was unable to find any alternatives to these two options, are there any more?

Comment: for  which element did you apply overflow:hidden ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What's your end goal?

Comment: Showing relevant code will make it easier to help you.

Comment: overflow: hidden; is the way to go. If it's not working you have some other problem in your css. Try html, body {overflow: hidden;} if this doesn't work try * {overflow: hidden;} and try figuring out what is wrong

Comment: **Use `height: 100%; overflow: hidden` styles for `<body>`** :)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Set `height` and `overflow`:

```
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q99hvawt/

Comment: forgot about "html, " before "body.

Comment: Not working on iOS when you have a overlay element that has fixed position.

Comment: You could just add the "overflow":"hidden" and it will work fine.

Comment: This solution did not immediately work for me, but after inspection "margin" was being overridden somewhere. Setting that element's "margin: 0;" did the trick.

Comment: Sometimes you would prefer using `height: 100vh` ; )

Comment: @neox5 Unfortunately, Safari is the new IE. And on iOS, every browser is just a wrapper for Safari. In Chrome on iOS, `100vh` includes the viewport and the browser chrome. Setting a height of `100vh` will actually make it too tall.

Comment: @neox5 You might want to look into `100dvh` or one of the other newer variants -- More info on the bug here: https://nicolas-hoizey.com/articles/2015/02/18/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers/

Answer (score 29):

To accomplish this, add 2 CSS properties on the `<body>` element.

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

These days there are many news websites which require users to create an account. Typically they will give full access to the page for about a second, and then they show a pop-up, and stop users from scrolling down.

[image: The Telegraph]

## EDIT

In addition, some websites (e.g. Quora) also make portions of text blurry. In general they do this by applying the following CSS.

```
filter: blur(3px);
```

Comment: this hides the scrollbar. However, the question is specifically asking for an alternative to hiding the scrollbar

Comment: @DataGeek , this does not only hide the scrollbar, it also stops the ability to scroll down. And as I understand that is what was asked for. i.e. not just hiding it, but also making it impossible to scroll down.

Answer (score 20):

HTML css works fine if body tag does nothing you can write as well

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
```

In this case overriding should be on the body tag, it is easier to control but sometimes gives headaches.

Comment: This is not valid HTML5

Comment: @mbomb007 Can you please comment on the mistake here related to HTML5?

Comment: @Ethan The `scroll` attribute is not valid on the `<body>` tag. It's not listed as valid on any spec I can find. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp); [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body); [Quackit](https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_body_tag.cfm)

Answer (score 18):

This post was helpful, but just wanted to share a slight alternative that may help others:

Setting `max-height` instead of `height` also does the trick. In my case, I'm disabling scrolling based on a class toggle. Setting `.someContainer {height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}` when the container's height is smaller than that of the viewport would stretch the container, which wouldn't be what you'd want. Setting `max-height` accounts for this, but if the container's height is greater than the viewport's when the content changes, still disables scrolling.

Comment: this saved my day for desktop browsers without unwanted side effect of scroll-top-top. but didn't work on mobile browsers (iphone5s and android).

Answer (score 12):

- Using React >= 17.8?
- Want to do this conditionally?

`useEffect` to the rescue!

```
function useImperativeDisableScroll({ element, disabled }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!element) {
            return
        }

        element.style.overflowY = disabled ? 'hidden' : 'scroll'

        return () => {
            element.style.overflowY = 'scroll'
        }
    }, [disabled])
}
```

You could use this with e.g.

```
useImperativeDisableScroll({ element: document.body, disabled: true })
```

Depending on your use case, you may have better luck with

```
useImperativeDisableScroll({
    element: document.scrollingElement,
    disabled: true
})
```

Note however that at time of writing, you might have to polyfill `document.scrollingElement`.

Useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement
- https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-document-scrollingelement
- https://caniuse.com/document-scrollingelement
- https://github.com/yangg/scrolling-element

Answer (score 12):

There is another convenient way to disable scrolling without dynamically changing the body element when you need to create a popup component for your web app.
First, add this style:

```
body:has(.requires-no-scroll) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, when you create/open any popup, just add this class to it, and its presence will block the scrolling automatically (and unblock it as you remove the popup):

```
<div class="popup requires-no-scroll">
  ...
</div>
```

This is good for reactive apps when you show the popup based on some reactive boolean variable: the scrolling blocks by itself and you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I like this elegant solution (disregarding the probably costly selector). It worked when I failed with an [`overscroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) solution. `:has` still won’t work in Firefox, but okay.

Answer (score 6):

This would prevent page scroll:

```
body, html {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with the page scrolling to the top. you can do:

```
position: fixed;
```

on the element you don't want to be scrollable. I know it's not the answer you wanted but I'm answering the title directly for those who Googled for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable scrolling on the main child of your body but not the body itself (out of necessity/other reasons) you could apply such a class to it.

```
.app {
   height: 100vh;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   filter: blur(npx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<body id="appBody">
....
</body>
```

JS

```
function disableBodyScroll(){
 const element = document.querySelector("#appBody");
 element.classList.add("stop-scroll");
}

function enableBodyScroll(){
 const element = document.querySelector("#appBody");
 element.classList.remove("stop-scroll");
}
```

CSS

```
 .stop-scroll {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: bbc seems to use some combo of above can be made viewable by setting something like 
height: 200vh;
max-height: 200vh;
overflow: auto;
on the main element. It's not obvious how they actually prevent the scroll. e.g. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-tyne-58925807

Comment: Can also be circumvented by disabling javascript

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling as much as i am. If your root element is `Html` then add `overflow: hidden` to it instead of `body`