# Disabling the scroll when the modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to disable scrolling when the modal opens. I've seen discussions about  this referring to bootstrap, but I'm not using bootstrap, all my code is custom. Is there any way I can incorporate this method with the code below:

```
function mobileNav() {
  $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function(){
    var status = $(this).hasClass('is-open');
    if(status){
      $('.menu-toggle,.side-menu,').removeClass('is-open');
    }else {
      $('.menu-toggle,.side-menu').addClass('is-open');
    }
});
```

([Code as a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BORfv.png))

Comment: Add your code, not just an image of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened)

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28411556/1760313

Comment: Hey man, welcome to StackOverflow! There are a lot of answers here already about how to achieve this, mainly javascript solutions toggling a class in the body tag. You would get a much better response/answer if you provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). An alternative to the JS solutions you will find, the same thing can be achieved with pure CSS. [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/wn6atzeL/).

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Sorry, I'm new to this and was having problems posting the code. My only solution was to post an image instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the modal, add the following css to body:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: hidden` in the css of the modal to prevent scrolling.

JQuery has a useful function called `toggleClass` which would make your code more readable.

Comment: I've added a class to the body, but when I check to see if it works in the inspector it doesn't appear. Thanks for answering my question.